# Password protection using jQuery

Tags: jquery, passwords

I want to password protect my website.

I have found this code from another developer but want it to redirect to `index3.html` when the password entered is correct.

Can someone please show me if this is possible using this code?

http://jsfiddle.net/LpdQm/16/

```
$("#b").click(function() {
    var password = "password";
    if($("#pass").val() !== password) {
        $("#err").text("Incorrect password");
    }
    else {
        $("#err").text("Password correct! Do whatever you need to do here.");   
    }
});
```

Comment: umad? JavaScript password protection is like putting a image of a lock onto your door. Either use PHP authentication with a form, or a password protection with htaccess and htpasswd

Comment: is that not possible? or do i have to use php?

Comment: @PaulDesigner: You don't have to use PHP specifically, but you should use server-side code where the users can't view the actual password being compared against.  If you use JavaScript to check against a known password then any user can just look at the code and see that password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is redirect the user, then replace this:

```
$("#err").text("Password correct! Do whatever you need to do here.");
```

with this:

```
window.location.href = "http://someUrl";
```

where "someUrl" is the URL to which you want to direct the user.

***However***, as noted in the comments on the question itself, JavaScript-based password protection like this will ***not*** be secure.  Any user can simply view the JavaScript source code and see what the expected password is.  For any kind of security you'll want to use some kind of server-side password check, where the user can't see the code.  There are a lot of options for this (PHP, Ruby, Python, ASP.NET, Java, the list goes on and on), which one you choose is up to you.